# Getting Error installing new laravel project with php8?

Tags: php, laravel

my PHP version: PHP 8.0.0rc1

When I'm trying to install a new laravel project with `laravel new project-name` command, i get this errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- This package requires php ^7.3 but your PHP version (8.0.0rc1) does not satisfy that 
requirement.
Problem 2
- Installation request for asm89/stack-cors v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by asm89/stack- 
cors[v2.0.1].
- asm89/stack-cors v2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.0rc1) does not satisfy 
that requirement.
Problem 3
- Installation request for laravel/framework v8.10.0 -> satisfiable by 
laravel/framework[v8.10.0].
- laravel/framework v8.10.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring 
is missing from your system.
.
.
.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
.
.
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

is there any problem with my composer or my php version?

Comment: You're trying to used non-stable versions of things. Perhaps raise the issues with the relevant developers.

Comment: There isn't a problem with Composer and only one of the problems is to do with the PHP install itself. The first package you're trying to pull in is constrained by `php ^7.3` meaning 7.3 and above but lower than 8 will satisfy it. Problem 2 is the same but with `^7.0` instead. Here is a representation: [https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/^7.3/8](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/^7.3/8) . Problem 3 is saying that you're version of PHP doesn't have the `mbstring` extension enabled.